# Cascade remove does not work for self-referenced JPA entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.1

I have category manu entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CATEGORIES")
public class Category {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    @JoinTable(name = "category_subcategory", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "category_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "subcategory_id"))
    private Set<Category> subcategories = new HashSet<>();
```

when I do remove I am getting next exception:

```
    SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement] with root cause
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: error: UPDATE or DELETE in table "categories" violates a foreign key constraint "fk_80ww4t7xfle796ryo5ausl44h"  from table "category_subcategory"
Details: On key (id) = (6) is still referenced in the table "category_subcategory".
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2102)
```

Please help to solve this truble, thanks!

Comment: so by deleteing parant I also want to delete all his childrance too, cascade should works but in this situation not.

Comment: Try using [`orphanRemoval=true`](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/delete#Orphan_Removal_)

Comment: thanks but not helped